# How do I re-enable MathJax after turning it off?

Tags: support, mathjax

I accidentally turned off MathJax on a comment so I could see the LaTex source, and I don't know how to turn it back on again. I turned it off by right clicking in my browser, but now when I right click, I get a Firefox menu instead of a MathJax menu. Please help!

Comment: By switching of MathJax you mean that you have changed MathJax renderer to "Plain Source"? If yes, you can switch it back in the same way - just remember that to get into MathJax menu you need right click *on some MathJax formula*. See also: [How do I change Math Renderer for MathJax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30859)

Comment: Yes, probably. But, as I mentioned, the menu no longer appears to let me switch it back.

Comment: Even if I change the renderer mode to Plain source, I still see the MathJax menu under right click. One thing you can try is delete the cookie mjx.menu for math.stackexchange.com and restart the browser. I believe that cookie is the one storing your preference of renderer..

Comment: Maybe I was right clicking on some text that wasn’t rendered with MathJax or something. I haven’t tried to reproduce the problem because there’s a menu item to show the source in a pop-up that works even better that changing the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone else will find this useful some day.

I noticed that, for a split second, MathJax was rendering type-set equations before it was rendering the source. I was able to very quickly reload the page with Cmd-R (on the Mac) while quickly right clicking. That gave me the menu I was missing.

Was this a coincidence? Perhaps. I was also trying bookmarklets from [this web page](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html), which indeed caused proper rendering, but did not seem to affect pages on this web site. It may also be the case that I was not right clicking exactly on top of the LaTex source.

Comment: Did this occur in a chatroom?

Comment: No, it was on an uneditable comment from which I wanted to copy the LaTex.

Comment: Wait.... Apple mice have two buttons now?!??!?!!?!?