# Vertical space between superscript and square root sign

Tags: discussion, bug, mathjax, equation

## Background [TL;DR]

In [Difference between Ornstein-Uhlenbeck, Vasicek and Geometric Mean Reversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3977333/290189), the radicals in these two equations

$$S_{T,i}=\exp\left(\ln(S_0)e^{-\alpha T}+\left(\theta-\frac{\sigma^2}{4\alpha}\right)(1-e^{-\alpha T})+\sqrt{(1-e^{-2\alpha T})\frac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha}}\epsilon_i\right)$$
and
$$\ln(X_{t})=\ln(X_{t-1})e^{-\theta \Delta t}+\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha}\right)(1-e^{-\theta \Delta t})+\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\alpha}(1-e^{-2\theta \Delta t})}\epsilon_i$$
doesn't look good as the superscript and the square root overlaps.

## MWE (min. working example)

`$\sqrt{a^2}$` gives $\sqrt{a^2}$.

## Technical info

- My browser: Opera 71.0.3770.198
- My OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (upgraded from 18.04 LTS)

## Raison d'être

The overlapping and/or lack of vertical space between the radical sign and the superscript/numerator make reading difficult.  Imagine that we have the square root of $e$ to the power $\overline{X}$ `$\sqrt{e^\overline{X}}$` $\sqrt{e^\overline{X}}$.  That would create confusion in reading.

## Screenshot

I'm sure that's a problem in the MathJax library as I can't reproduce this using pdf$\rm\LaTeX$.

[image: pdfLaTeX vs MathJax sqrt overlapping]

---

[image: opera vs firefox]
Opera vs Firefox: the later renders the math normally

From the comments, it seems that it's a browser-specific problem.  Thanks for feedback.

Comment: fwiw I see no issues on my iPhone. Have you tried changing the math renderer?

Comment: Doesn't overlap for me (though there's only little space between the square in the numerator and the vinculum, but $\sqrt{e^{\overline{X}}}$ has plenty enough). What's your browser?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Can you clarify what "math renderer" means?  It is synonymous to "math rendering system" in the sense of [MathJax's official page](//www.mathjax.org) or "math renderer" as in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8881/290189?

Comment: No overlap for me on Chrome 87.0.4280.88 64-bit on Windows 10 with HTML-CSS.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've [edit]ed my post in response to your question.  It's Opera 71.  Thanks Matt for your info.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I meant it in the second sense. Oddly I cannot find it explicitly named in the MathJax documentation; but it appears [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/upgrading/earlier/whats-new-2.0.html?highlight=renderer) (ctrl+F for default renderer). To find it, rightclick on any rendered MathJax then go Math Settings > Math Renderer .

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks for explaining.  I tested this on my laptop.  I've testing some math renderers like custom HTML and MathML, but I find the math display by the default one (HTML-CSS) much prettier than the other ones that I had tried.

Comment: The spacing looks OK for Math Renderer HTML-CSS in Safari 14.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `^\phantom{a}` to create extra vertical space: `$\sqrt{e^{\overline{X}^\phantom{a}}}$` gives $\sqrt{e^{\overline{X}^\phantom{a}}}$.