# scaling root problem

Tags: discussion, bug, mathjax

## Background [TL;DR]

In my previous meta question [Vertical space between superscript and square root sign](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32986/290189), I attempted (not so successfully) to illustrate a display problem about the square root sign by `$\sqrt{e^\overline{X}}$`: $\sqrt{e^\overline{X}}$.

I had thought about enlarging this: `${\Huge \sqrt{e^\overline{X}}}$`: ${\Huge \sqrt{e^\overline{X}}}$, but the stroke going northeast $\nearrow$ surpasses the horizontal stroke going to the right-hand side $\to$.

[image: screenshot on opera]
Screenshot using Opera 71 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

## MWE (min. working example)

```
$$\sqrt{a}$$
$$\Large{\sqrt{a}}$$
$$\Huge{\sqrt{a}}$$
```

$$\sqrt{a}$$
$$\Large{\sqrt{a}}$$
$$\Huge{\sqrt{a}}$$

## Screenshot

[image: square root display problem by Firefox]
Screenshot taken by Firefox 84.0.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

## Expected output

The right-upward directed stroke $\nearrow$ and the horizontal stroke $\to$ are perfectly joined together as shown in the following image, but without the vertical stroke $\downarrow$.

[image: expected output]
image source: [Badly scaling closing SQRT symbol with large font sizes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449254/126386) on $\rm\TeX$.SE

Comment: I see the same on Chromium 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for comment.  I've [edit]ed my question to include the expected output, which I had omitted carelessly.

Comment: possibly related - https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1044

Comment: Totally off-topic. In order I "see" and enjoy the "name" my wife did print it using a 96 font size, framed it for decorating my office.

Comment: Maybe something can be achieved using `\strut` or [`\mathstrut`](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm#mathstrut), but the closest I got is `\Large{\sqrt{\Huge{\mathstrut a}}}`
$$\Large{\sqrt{\Huge{\mathstrut a}}}$$ which is a bit emaciated.

Comment: It turns out that this is a bug in the HTML-CSS output of MathJax, where one term in the positioning of the overline doesn't take the scaling into account, so the line is misplaced, and the error is more pronounced the larger the scaling factor is.  I have made a [issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2615) and accompanying pull request to resolve the issue.  It will be fixed in the next v2 release (though StackExchange is using v2.7.5 rather than the current v2.7.9).

Comment: I wonder if there's an OS / font / screen resolution dependency too? I'm on Firefox 84.0.2 on MacOS Big Sur (and using the HTML-CSS math renderer) and all the examples on this page look fine to me. I do see a slight discrepancy in the overline height on Chrome, but not nearly as much as in the screenshots others have posted. Weird…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither a solution nor an analysis of the inner working of MathJax. Just posting

> `${\sqrt{\Huge{e^\overline{X}}}}$`

for comparison:

${\sqrt{\Huge{e^\overline{X}}}}$

This looks better on my screen (Firefox, version 84), but may be is not quite what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for response.  I go with everything in this answer expect the last half-sentence.

Comment: See [Davide Cervone's reply to a related question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33014/11619). In particular for the description of the surd sizes. He works for MathJax, so knows what's going on. The reasoning that lead me to try this is the following. The size of the surd `\sqrt` tries to automagically match the box that follows. So if `Huge` is desired, we only need to make the contents of that box huge, and the surd will follow suit. In light of that it does not really make sense to try and apply a modifier to the surd itself.