# Can no longer quickly preview LaTeX on MSE

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown-preview

It used to be that every time I wrote a question, the LaTeX in the preview would almost instantly compile. As of this week, I have to wait several seconds before seeing it appear. Nothing on my end (OS, browser, browser settings etc.) changed, what changed on this site?

Comment: I have also noticed this happening, and sometimes it's quite a bit longer than just a few seconds. This would be a nightmare for a user new to LaTex formatting...

Comment: Are you talking [about the preview](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/markdown-preview/info) or about the final question (after posting)? In case it helps, I will point out that you can choose various MathJax renderers: [How do I change Math Renderer for MathJax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30859) and [What is the difference between the 3 math renderers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8881)

Comment: My impression after the recent design revamp was that rendering seemed to have slowed somewhat, got used to that; then, earlier, while I was searching for posts, the mathjax wouldn't render in the results preview, like how the OP is describing (@MartinSleziak we are referring to the final posts, not the submission previews), so I turned off all browser extensions to verify that they aren't the culprit (some extensions are resource hogs), yet the issue is persisting. In case switching renderer helps, Martin, which renderer is the leanest and quickest?

Comment: @ryang The question which MathJax renderer is fastest is probably a question for somebody who knows more about this that I do. (Naturally, anybody can try their own experiments.) The name suggests that Preview HTML is fast - but does not look too well. My guess would be that Common HTML might be relatively fast. 
An answer to one of the linked post says about SVG that "there should be no dependence on local fonts (but it's generally slow to render, at least in my experience)".

Comment: It will be interesting to see whether this changes after [switching to a newer version of MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35316). But at the moment, it is not clear if SE plans to do that. (And if yes, we do not know when.)

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: @MartinSleziak It turns out that on my system, the only satisfactory renderer is the one I've been using all along, HTML-CSS. The other ones either don't look good, or pose issues when trying to copy symbols by selecting-then-copying.

Comment: I also have the same problem

Comment: @MartinSleziak The markdown preview

Comment: I tried this on a Chrome browser with Windows OS and Safari browser with macOS. On the former, there is no issue with rendering, but on the latter, the render is extremely slow and I cannot put (lower or upper) indices on a summation symbol. Any attempt to put an index on the summation symbol makes the entire mathematical expression not render.

Comment: @MartinSleziak This issue is related to [this new report](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35557/21813). Additionally: recently, the issue (mathjax, during preview, either refusing or taking forever to render) seemed to have resolved, but it started recurring yesterday.